# Querying items with multiple related data items (Sitefinity)

Tags: c#, .net, sitefinity

I was referring to this article for querying dynamic content with related data:

https://docs.sitefinity.com/example-query-dynamic-content-by-related-data

This is all well and good when dealing with single related item, but currently I am dealing with this scenario:

I have a custom content item of Human, and two related data items of type Hair Color and Eye Color (these are just example types of course)

Suppose I wanted to query all Human items with Hazel eyes and black hair, how can I do that in a clean way?

I came up with a hacky solution, but I need something that will work with either no related data query needed, or with one or both (all combinations)

Is there a tried and true way of doing this with Sitefinity's native API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cleanest way is to use the ContentLinksManager in addition to the DynamicModuleManager.

Here is pseudo code:

1. using the DynamicModuleManager get the OriginalContentId of the HairColor item (from the HairColor module) where Color == "Black"
2. using the DynamicModuleManager get the OriginalContentId of the EyeColor item (from the EyeColor module) where EyeColor == "Hazel"
3. Then

   ```
   var cmanager = ContentLinksManager.GetManager(); var humanWithBlackHairMasterIds = cmanager
                     .GetContentLinks()
                     .Where(c => c.ParentItemType == "Human type" &&
                                 c.ChildItemType == "HairColor type" &&
                                 c.IsParentDeleted == false && 
                                 c.IsChildDeleted == false &&
                                 c.ChildItemId == ID_From_Point1)
               .Select(c => c.ParentItemId);
   ```

Now humanWithBlackHairMasterIds will have the masterIds of all humans with black hair.

You can do a similar thing with the Eye color module and get all humans with Hazel eyes and finally intersect both results to get the humans that satisfy both conditions.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks. 

This is sort of what I was doing already, just in a cleaner way. However, I was hoping there'd be something a little more fault tolerant in that:

I have an endpoint to get Human data. It takes in eye color and hair color as params, both are optional. The solutions that you and I have come up with seem dependent on having to retrieve at least one collection filtered by criteria.

If that's how it is though, then that's how it is. Sitefinity has not been so fun to work with. Thanks :)

Comment: You can always check if the eye color and hair color params are nulls and if so just return all humans, or did I not understand your concern?

Comment: I am currently do that, and if it was "both params or nothing" it would be fine

But currently I have to to write a whole separate block of code for:

Hair color but no eye color,
No hair color but eye color,
No hair color or eye color, and
Both Hair color and eye color